# Custom Redux Middleware - Dispatch to beginning of middleware chain?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am writing a custom middleware that needs to dispatch thunk actions.  The problem is that the middleware is called after `redux-thunk` in the middleware chain, so I get the error `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` when using the provided `dispatch`.

```
export default function createMiddleware() {
    return ({dispatch, getState}) => next => (action) => {
        if(action.type !== 'FOO') {
            return next(action);
        }

        dispatch(thunkActionHere); // this is the issue
    }
}
```

I would like to dispatch this thunk action back to the beginning of the middleware chain so that redux-thunk can handle it.  Is this possible?

update:

```
function createMiddleware(extraArgument) {
    return function ({dispatch, getState}) {
        return function (next) {
            return function (action) {
                switch (action.type) {
                    case 'FOO1':
                        dispatch({type: 'NORMAL_ACTION'}); // works fine
                        break;
                    case 'FOO2':
                        dispatch(function() {
                            return (dispatch, getState) => { // Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
                                console.log('inside the thunk');
                            };
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        return next(action);
                }
            };
        };
    };
}

const middleware = createMiddleware();
middleware.withExtraArgument = createMiddleware;

export default middleware;
```

Here's my store configuration:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
        // Add other middleware on this line...
        applyMiddleware(bugsnagErrorCatcherMiddleware()),
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({APIFactory, PusherManager})),
        applyMiddleware(webrtcVideoMiddleware.withExtraArgument(PusherManager)), // this is the middleware above
        applyMiddleware(bugsnagbreadcrumbLoggerMiddleware()),
        )
    );

    return store;
}
```

I cannot put my middleware before redux-thunk because then it doesn't receive actions that thunks dispatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was in my store configuration.  Using redux's `compose` caused the issue.

before:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../redux/reducers';
import webrtcVideoMiddleware from '../redux/middleware/webrtcVideo';
import bugsnagErrorCatcherMiddleware from '../redux/middleware/bugsnag/errorCatcher';
import bugsnagbreadcrumbLoggerMiddleware from '../redux/middleware/bugsnag/breadcrumbLogger';
import * as APIFactory from '../services/APIFactory';
import Pusher from '../services/PusherManager';

const PusherManager = new Pusher(false);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
        applyMiddleware(bugsnagErrorCatcherMiddleware()),
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({APIFactory, PusherManager})),
        applyMiddleware(webrtcVideoMiddleware(PusherManager)),
        applyMiddleware(bugsnagbreadcrumbLoggerMiddleware())
    ));
}
```

after:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../redux/reducers';
import webRTCVideoMiddleware from '../redux/middleware/webrtcVideo';
import bugsnagErrorCatcherMiddleware from '../redux/middleware/bugsnag/errorCatcher';
import bugsnagBreadcrumbLoggerMiddleware from '../redux/middleware/bugsnag/breadcrumbLogger';
import * as APIFactory from '../services/APIFactory';
import Pusher from '../services/PusherManager';

const PusherManager = new Pusher(false);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const middleware = [
        bugsnagErrorCatcherMiddleware(),
        thunk.withExtraArgument({APIFactory, PusherManager}),
        webRTCVideoMiddleware.withExtraArgument(PusherManager),
        bugsnagBreadcrumbLoggerMiddleware(),
    ];

    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Dispatching inside the middleware chain will send the action to the start of the middleware chain, and will call the thunk as usual ([Demo](http://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/dNambR) - look at the console).

**Why?**

The original `store.dispatch()` (before applying middlewares) checks if the action is a plain POJO, and if not throws an error:

```
  function dispatch(action) {
    if (!isPlainObject(action)) {
      throw new Error(
        'Actions must be plain objects. ' +
        'Use custom middleware for async actions.'
      )
    }
```

When you `applyMiddleware()` the `dispatch` is replaced by a new method, which is the chain of middleware, that call the original `store.dispatch()` in the end. You can see it in the [applyMiddleware](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js) method:

```
export default function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {
  return (createStore) => (reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) => {
    const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer)
    let dispatch = store.dispatch // dispatch is now the original store's dispatch
    let chain = []

    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (action) => dispatch(action) // this refers to the dispatch variable. However, it's not the original dispatch, but the one that was created by compose
    }
    chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
    dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch) // dispatch is a composition of the chain, with the original dispatch in the end

    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch
    }
  }
}
```

btw - change your middleware to this, since the 1st function will prevent your middleware from working.

```
export default const createMiddleware = ({dispatch, getState}) => next =>   (action) => {
    if(action.type !== 'FOO') {
        return next(action);
    }

    dispatch(thunkActionHere); // this is the issue
}
```

Comment: It turns out the issue was in my store configuration.  Using redux's `compose` caused the issue.

Comment: Can you add it as another answer? It's interesting.

Comment: sure thing, just did

Answer (score 2):

We use `composeWithDevTools` from [redux-devtools-extension](http://extension.remotedev.io/#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm). Same issue and same solution as noted above. Just needed to move to using `applyMiddleware(...middlewares)` instead of multiple `applyMiddleware(middleware), applyMiddleware(middleware)` as arguments to the composition.