# Dispatch event in middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two middlewares in my react-redux app.

1. The first is API middle which sends requests to server and parses answer from it.
2. The second is Auth middleware which stores JWT in localstorage and check if responce from server was 401 code, we have to refresh our JWT.

In the second middleware I try to call `store.dispatch`. In redux devToolsExtension I can see new action but this action does not go to the first middleware..

Code.
The first middleware:

```
const apiMiddleware = store => next => action => {

    const {api, type, ...rest} = action;
    if (!api) {
        return next(action);
    }

    next({
        type: type + START,
        ...rest
    });

    const { url } = api;
    let params = getParamsForApiCall(api);
    let statusCode;

    // TODO timeout from settings
    timeout(5000, fetch(url, params).then(response => {
        statusCode = processResponse(response);
        return response.text();
    //
    })).then(text => {
        let nextType = processAnwer(text, statusCode);
        let typeResult = type + nextType;
        console.log('Type result action: ', typeResult);

        return next({type: typeResult, statusCode, responce: text, ...rest})
    //
    }).catch(error => {
        processError(error)
    })
};
```

The second:

```
import {SUCCESS, UNAUTH} from "../../Constants";
import {USER, LOGIN, CHECK_JWT, REFRESH_TOKEN, LOGOUT, userRefreshToken, userLogout } from "../AC/User"
import { HTTP_CODE_UNAUTH }  from "../../Constants/http"

import { saveJWTToStore, clearJWTFormStore } from '../../Utils/jwt'

const authMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    const { type, statusCode, responce, ...rest } = action;

    next(action);

    switch (type) {
    case USER + REFRESH_TOKEN + UNAUTH:
    case USER + CHECK_JWT + UNAUTH:
        console.log('UNAUTH have to logout');
        dispatch(userLogout());
        break;
    // ---------
    case USER + CHECK_JWT + SUCCESS:
    case USER + LOGIN + SUCCESS:
        let obj = JSON.parse(responce);
        let token = obj['token'];
        action = Object.assign(action, {token: token});
        saveJWTToStore(token);
        break;
    // ---------
    case USER + LOGOUT:
        console.log('Remove JWT from localStore');
        clearJWTFormStore();
        break;
    // ---------
    default:
      let errAuth = statusCode === HTTP_CODE_UNAUTH;
      if (errAuth) {
        console.log(`Need to refresh JWT`);

        // !!! this dispatch does not word as well
        dispatch(userRefreshToken());
      }

    }
};

export default authMiddleware;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of convention for writing middleware is you should always return result of `next()`. This is to make sure middleware return another version of store and keep the middleware chain work well.
Back to your sample above, in your second middleware, you don't return value of next(), hence the other middleware don't receive your updated store. To fix it:

```
let result = next(action);
...
return result;
```

or simply:

```
...
return next(action);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've tried this solutions too and it does not work as well) I found the solution this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217369/custom-redux-middleware-dispatch-to-beginning-of-middleware-chain. Maybe it will be hopefull for someone.

Comment: Could you post here what did you change? It would be helpful for others

Comment: There is an answer in the link which I posted.

Comment: Cool, so it's the problem with setting up store with middleware? I think it's also recommended to return next() inside your middleware as well.

Comment: Yes and yes) Recommended way to return next() does not work. But solutions with use applyMiddleware(...middlewares) works well.